# Find closest element in array jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array of elements

```
var allParents = $section.find("a:not(.k-dsgn-stval)");

allParents = allParents.filter(function () {
                if($(this).children("i.k-dsgn-stval").length === 1) {
                    return false;
                }
                
                if ($(this).parent(".k-dsgn-paramowner").length === 1) {
                    return true;
                }
                
      
                if($(this).parent("li").parent("ul").prev(".k-dsgn-paramowner").length === 1)
                {
                    var $ul = $(this).parent("li").parent("ul");
                    
                    if(!$ul.prev(".k-dsgn-paramowner").hasClass("k-dsgn-inlineparam")){
                        return true;
                    }
                    
                    if($ul.prev(".k-dsgn-paramowner").text().trim() == "then (") {
                        if($(this).parent("li").index() === 0) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                return false;
            });


        var item = null;
        var $item = $(this);

        if ($item.parents(".k-dsgn-paramowner").length > 0) {
            item = $item.parents(".k-dsgn-paramowner").first();
        } else if ($item.siblings(".k-dsgn-paramowner").length > 0) {
            if($item.siblings(".k-dsgn-paramowner").first().find("a").length > 0) {
                item = $item.siblings(".k-dsgn-paramowner").first();
            } else {
                item = $item.parent().siblings(".k-dsgn-paramowner").first();
            }
        } else {
            if($item.parents("ul").first().siblings(".k-dsgn-paramowner").first().find("a").length > 0) {
               item = $item.parents("ul").first().siblings(".k-dsgn-paramowner").first();
            } else {
                item = $item.parents("ul").first().parent().siblings(".k-dsgn-paramowner").first();
            }
        }
```

I have other tags that are focused and I want to find the closest element in the array to the current elements.Tried with a big dirty if else but would. like a cleaner way of doing this. thought closest would work but it doesn't.

Comment: Check closest() function

Comment: Did you tried to get the index of the element inside the array and the index of the element in html and compare them  with `closest()` function ?

Comment: closest() doesn't seem to work on an array of elements,  can you show me @AhmedTagAmer

Comment: I'ver updated the code so its more like the real. problem @pc_coder

Comment: please show what you have done to solve this problem?, THE `I want to` isn't a good option

Comment: be specific @Adam

Comment: @AhmedAli I've updated the code to show the if statement i have used to find the closest element in the array. i'd like to see if anyone knows of a better way of doing it